# google currency api (result by date)

Tags: c#, web-services, google-api, yahoo-api

this is how i convert currency in my code

and it works good

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR");

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string json_result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

what i want to do is to get the same data but for past dates(exact by day)

is there a way to do it? (by Google or by different API)

thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some intensive Googling I found this:
http://currencies.apps.grandtrunk.net/

They have a web service you can use:
http://currencies.apps.grandtrunk.net/getrate/2009-11-15/usd/zar

The last link represents the USD to ZAR rate on the 15th of November 2009.